# Переменная JS и Ajax.BeginForm(). Как передать

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc

Привет если ajax запрос через форму

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("edit", "Home",
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = "record-table",
                    HttpMethod = "Post"
                }, new { @class = "EditForm" }))
                    {
                       @Html.TextBox("EditId", null, new { @value = "", @class = "form-control", @required = "" }).
                    }
```

У менять есть переменная js и я хочу ее передать  в свойстве value  но как записать ее туда Не обязательно в валуе(можно и в имени или как 2 аргумент где null там переедаются данные для отправки просто не знаю как связать js и форму) просто хочу передать в контроллер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил не много не так как хотел но результат нужный

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".btn.btn-success.goedit").click(function () {
                $(".form-control.editId").val(CurrentId);
            });
        });

$(".form-control.editId").val(CurrentId);
```

скрытый input и  из него передаю